# PSQL : Silencing a function call's output, or calling it without SELECT

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, I have an UPDATE rule on a table which only needs to call a `dctUpdate` function without doing a whole SQL statement, since the SQL statement is actually done in the function. The only way I know of calling the function is through `SELECT dctUpdate(windowId)`:

```
create or replace function infoUpdate(windowId in numeric) returns void as $$
begin
    if windowId is null then
        update info_timestamp set timestamp = now();
    else
        update info_timestamp set timestamp = now() where window_id = windowId;
    end if;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


create or replace rule info_update_rule as on update to some_table do also select infoUpdate(NEW.window_id);
```

However, on the command line, when that rule gets triggered because I updated a row in `some_table`, I get useless output from the `SELECT` clause that calls the function :

```
db=# update some_table set name = 'foobar' where window_id = 1;
 infoupdate 
-----------

(1 row)

UPDATE 1
```

Is there a way to have `info_update_rule` call the `infoUpdate` function without it displaying dummy output?

Comment: Do you really mean to set **all** the timestamps in the whole table to `now()` if just the new `window_id` is NULL? And which versions of PostgreSQL do you need to support?

Comment: @mu : yes, I mean to set all the timestamps when NULL, and I support PostgreSQL 9.0 and up

Answer (score 1):

I've found no options to implement this using rules, but there is an alternative way of implementing this usign triggers.

So, you define trigger function as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ur_wrapper_trg()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
    perform infoUpdate(NEW.window_id);
    RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ur_wrapper_trg() OWNER TO postgres;
```

Note [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html) syntax is used. This syntax is identical to `SELECT` syntax except it supresses all output.

Than you define a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_table_utrg
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON some_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE ur_wrapper_trg();
```

In the end, you remve your rule.

Haven't tested with `null`, but with actual `windos_id`s works as expected, without any unwanted output.

Consult with [Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/triggers.html) and [Rules vs triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/rules-triggers.html) for detailed description.

Comment: I can't use triggers for performance reasons. This rule will apply on queries that update several thousands of rows on a mission critical system, and calling a trigger for each one of those rows would be much too expensive, which is why I have to do it with rules. I still prefer getting garbage output to taking a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

The closes solution to which I came is to call `\t \a` before `select function()` and right after it. The only remaining thing is a new line for each call.